# exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vmware, packer

I am trying to pull centos image using packer. Below is the error message received when i build it. Do I need to download vmware into my base machine(Ubuntu 16.04). I have copied below code from below site. https://selfieblue.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/step-by-step-building-vargant-centos7-image-from-packer-by-using-vmware-10-on-windows-8-1/

Error Message-

```
root@sonatapack:~# packer build packer.json
vmware-iso output will be in this color.

Build 'vmware-iso' errored: Failed creating VMware driver: Unable to initialize any driver for this platform. The errors
from each driver are shown below. Please fix at least one driver
to continue:
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH


==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vmware-iso: Failed creating VMware driver: Unable to initialize any driver for this platform. The errors
from each driver are shown below. Please fix at least one driver
to continue:
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH


==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Below is my json file.

```
    {
  "variables": {
    "ssh_name": "packer",
    "ssh_pass": "admin123"
  },
  "builders": [{
     "type": "vmware-iso",
     "iso_url": "http://vault.centos.org/6.5/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso",
     "iso_checksum_type" : "md5",
     "iso_checksum" : "83221db52687c7b857e65bfe60787838",
     "disk_size" : 30720,
     "ssh_username" : "vagrant",
     "ssh_password" : "vagrant",
     "ssh_wait_timeout" : "30m",
     "shutdown_command" : "sudo shutdown -P now",
     "vmx_data": {
        "memsize": "4096",
        "numvcpus": "2"
        }
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": [
      "sleep 30",
      "echo Congratulation!",
      "echo Next process is exporting image in Vargrant format"
    ]
  }],
  "post-processors": [{
    "type" : "vagrant"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have VMware Workstation or VMware Player (with some hacks) installed, see the [docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware.html).

Comment: Could you help me out in setting up this

Comment: Haven't used either of them so no. But VMware Workstation is a paid product which includes support so there should be no problem getting that to work. VMware Player is free but requires some tricks to get to work with Packer, try searching or posting on the packer-tool mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/packer-tool